# Cancel join condition based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am stuck into a situation where I need to perform conditional join. The brief summary could be, I have 2 tables `TableA` and `TableB`.

`TableA` has columns `A1`,`A2`,`A3`,`A4`,`A5`,`Condition1`,`Condition2`

similarly `TableB` has columns `B1`,`B2`,`Condition1`,`Condition2`

And I need to perform join on `TableA.Condition1 = TableB.Condition1` and condition join on `TableA.Condition2 = TableB.Condition2`, condition being `TableA.Condition2` should not be null for any record first join.

In other words, if I some any record with `TableA.Condition1 = TableB.Condition1` matched and at the same time `TableA.Condition2` is not null for any of them then perform second join, otherwise don't perform second join.

Query could be like

```
SELECT A.* FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON A.Condition1 = B.Condition1 -- This must be perform
AND WHEN A.Condition2 IS NULL THEN
1 = 1 -- Assuming no join here
ELSE
A.Condition2 = B.Condition2 -- perform join
END
```

Comment: Your obfuscation of the actual details is probably making this harder for any real solutions.  If you can provide non confidential / private information and actual context table/columns would definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting from `TableA`, so how about using `exists` instead?

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TableA A
WHERE (A.Condition2 IS NULL AND
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE A.Condition1 = B.Condition1)
      ) AND
      (A.Condition2 IS NOT NULL AND
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE A.Condition1 = B.Condition1 AND A.Condition2 = B.Condition2)
      );
```

Or, if you want a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TableA A JOIN
     TableB B
     ON A.Condition1 = B.Condition1 AND
        (A.Condition2 IS NOT NULL OR A.Condition2 = B.Condition2);
```

Comment: Talking about join solution, I have mentioned in question that if any value for Condition2 of TableA is not null then that join must be performed. Your question is always picking data when the same is null, even though few records have that value as not null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.Condition1 = B.Condition1 AND
                       ((A.Condition2 IS NOT NULL  AND A.Condition2 = B.Condition2) 
                        OR (A.Condition2 IS NULL) )
```

Comment: I have mentioned in question that if any value for Condition2 of TableA is not null then that join must be performed. Your question is always picking data when the same is null, even though few records have that value as not null.

Comment: @Imad I have updated Ans, Try it let me know if it helpful for you

Comment: Still the same output :(

Answer (score 0):

hard to understand your question and even harder to understand the purpose

```
SELECT A.*
-- join table1 and table2 on Condition1
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B ON A.Condition1 = B.Condition1 
-- if max condition2 is null then there is nothing but nulls 
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(Condition2) Condition2 FROM TableA A2 ) A2 
-- in that case every row resulting from join1 goes
ON A2.Condition2 IS NULL
-- otherwise use condition2 but replace nulls with some placeholder 
-- or maybe you have either all null or no nulls
OR COALESCE (A.Condition2,'null') = COALESCE (B.Condition2,'null')
;
```